# Passing parameters to a Twig Macro

Tags: php, twig

I pass 2 parameters to a Twig macro but only one of them appears to be passed

```
{{currentPage}} //this is outputting the current page e.g. home 


{% macro render_menu(links, currentPage) %}

{% import _self as subnav %}

{% for code, link in links %}

{{currentPage}} //this is NOT outputting the current page

<li class="{{ code == currentPage ? 'active' }} {{ link.sublinks ? 'dropdown' }}">
```

I need to use currentPage to enable the 'active' menu item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you calling the macro? That part of the code is missing. Do note macro's have their own scope, this means they don't know any variable and you have to pass them explicitly

*macro.twig*

```
{% macro render_menu(links, currentPage) %}
    {% import _self as subnav %}
    {% for link in links %}
        <li class="{{ link.code == currentPage ? 'active' }} {{ link.sublinks ? 'dropdown' }}">
            <a href="{{ link.code }}">{{ link.code }}</a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endmacro %}
```

*main.twig*

```
{% import 'macro.twig' as macro %}

{{ macro.render_menu(links, currentPage) }}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/jddi05)

Comment: Yep, that prompted me to check where the macro was called and I had missed passing the currentPage argument. I changed {{ nav.render_menu(links) }} to {{ nav.render_menu(links, currentPage) }} and it worked. Thanks.