# Unable to display comment tree with twig macro

Tags: macros, twig

I am trying to render comment tree using twig macro but keep getting following error:

"Neither the property "comments" nor one of the methods "comments()", "getcomments()"/"iscomments()"/"hascomments()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection"."

If there is additional info needed, I am at disposal.

Br,

```php
{% macro render_comment(comment) %}
    <li id="comment-{{ comment.id }}">
        <span>
            {{ comment.author.fullName }}
            {{ 'post.commented_on'|trans }}
            {{ comment.publishedAt|format_datetime('medium', 'short', '', 'UTC') }}
        </span>
        {{ comment.content|markdown_to_html|sanitize_html }}

        <a href="#comment_content" data-reply data-id="{{ comment.id }}">
            {{ 'action.submit_reply'|trans }}
        </a>

        {% if comment.children is not empty %}
            <ul>
                {% for child in comment.children %}
                    {{ _self.render_comment(child) }}
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}
    </li>
{% endmacro %}

{% macro render_comment_list(comments) %}
    {% for comment in comments %}
        {% if comment.parent is null %}
            {{ _self.render_comment(comment) }}
        {% endif %}
    {% else %}
        {{ 'post.no_comments'|trans }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endmacro %}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing parameters to a Twig Macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56104660/passing-parameters-to-a-twig-macro)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `comments` too:

```
{{ render_comment_list(post, comments) }}
```

and make sure that when you render this template, you expose `comments` properly so it can reach them.

EDIT

As per the comment section

```
{{ render_comment_list(post.comments) }}
```

was the solution.

Comment: hi, sorry for leaving it out, comments property is array collection and it's passed into template via $post variable, so I do not think that this is an issue.

Comment: Macro's have their own variable scope and don't know about any variables passed to the template. However you can access every variable if pass the special variable `_context` which contains all know variables in the template.

Comment: hi, i have resolved error by adding {{ render_comment_list(post.comments) }} to main template, and changing {% for comment in post.comments %} to {% for comment in comments %}.